# OpenGL - Asymmetric Textures

Tags: opengl

Assume I have several images that I would like to pack into a single texture. The size of one dimension of every image is the same (I.E. All images have the same width but have different heights, or all images have the same height but varying widths). Would there be any advantages/disadvantages to packing all of the images into a very wide or very tall texture as opposed to packing the images into a square texture via a binary tree packing algorithm? For example, would it be a bad idea to use a texture with a size of 32x8192 as opposed to a texture with a size of 512x512? Technically, both textures would contain 262,144 pixels so I'm curious to know if they would perform equally well.

Comment: Choose whatever produces less unused texels. Other than that I see no difference.

Comment: There is such thing as `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE`, and it has to be at least 1024. Some older cards may not support 8k wide textures.